# "not" behavior in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

Why would the Scheme interpreter demand numeric arguments for `not`?

In my case:

`(not (= 1 2))` returned the following error:

```
-: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: #f
  context...:
   stdin::1135: not
```

This is rather contrary to my 20-minute experience with the SICP, according to which `not` is a logical composition operator and its operands are supposed to be logical too.

Here comes the funniest part: the error is *not reproducible*. I know it sounds stupid, but I launched Racket once, got this error, re-launched it and the error was gone (i.e. `not` switched to returning proper logical values). Does anybody have an idea why might that happen? Is there something that I'm unaware of that affects Scheme's or Racket's behavior?

Note: I didn't modify the environment in any way, in neither of the cases. The only thing I did was enter the expression above.

Comment: Are you actually comparing 1 and 2, or some variables whose values you assumed to be 1 and 2?  Or could there have been a typo or autocompletion to bitwise-not that would do a bit inversion rather than a logical negation and thus expect a number?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! No variables were used; as I said, the environment was left untouched. Could you please elaborate on bitwise-not? I was under the impression that Scheme only has one kind of `not` operator, though I could have missed something.

Comment: You tagged with both Scheme and Racket, which usually means Racket, so I looked in the Racket documentation and found the function [bitwise-not](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._bitwise-not%29%29).  It was just a though that maybe some autocompletion or something might have used bitwise-not instead of not.  But the error message doesn't look like that's what happened...

Comment: I'd actually think this might be more like some kind of line-buffering issue, or maybe an accidental redefinition of `not`.

Comment: The `-` in  `-:` suggests to me the error is from the minus operator and not `not` ?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor yes, it seems this isn't the case. But I'm more and more inclined to think it was a line-buffering issue, as you said. Accidental redefinition is also possible - I can't really remember it now, though :)

Comment: @soegaard wow, that's a find. I didn't give it a thought then, but in this particular line no `-` operators were used. Weird stuff.

Comment: Are you using the terminal or emacs?

Comment: @soegaard terminal

Comment: Do you still have the dots in `context...:` ?

Comment: @soegaard yep. These are in every error message and indicate that the error occured in code from stdin (as far as I understand)

Comment: Ah! I thought the `...` meant something was omitted. I have no idea why you got the error.

Comment: @soegaard :) Me too. But I'm strongly inclined to think it was my fault and I just forgot I modified the environment in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Just to say I did:

I tested `(not (= 1 2))` in guile, gambit, chicken, drracket 6.4 and they all returned `#t`, as expected.

So there must have been some problem in your installation or environment. To find it we need more information.